# What is the maximum number of joins allowed in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

What is the maximum number of joins allowed in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limitations for SQL Server are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

The number of tables per query is only limited by the amount of available resources.

Answer (score 12):

The other answers already give the direct answer to your question

> Limited only by available resources

However even if SQL Server successfully compiles a plan for your query that doesn't mean that you should. The more joins you have the exponentially larger the space of possible query plans will be and you may well get very sub optimal plans.

For a query with 12 joins the number of possible join orders is [28,158,588,057,600](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/06/optimizing-join-orders/). Additionally each join may be of three possible algorithms (hash, nested loops, merge)

In the book "SQL server 2005 practical troubleshooting" Cesar Galindo-Legaria says

> If you are joining over 20 tables, chances are the optimizer is not
>   reviewing the entire search space but relying more on heuristics ....
>   we have seen applications that run regular queries dealing with over
>   100 tables. While it is possible to run such very large queries, you
>   really are stretching the system in these cases and should be very
>   careful going this far

Comment: As per Microsoft Guidelines, more than five tables are not allowed to join in SQL Server. Is it correct? If not correct, as per your perspective how many tables are allowed to join in SQL Server for better performance.

Comment: @RGS Max of 5 is a good recommendation. For left joins on one table that would be 120 possible query plans and for other scenario's up to 1680 plans. You'll have a fair chance that SQL will make a good choice out of those. In some cases more can be justified depending on the query and size of the tables (your time needed to code / performance gain). As for what is "allowed" depends on your policy, but technically you are "allowed" to waist resources, energy and time. Like you are "allowed" to burp out loud at the office. If you go out of bounds you risk being laid off for being incompetent.

Comment: I have this query, probably like 13 left joins.. Some of them joining the same table. Overall the query returns 1 tuple. What would be the best way to optimize? Does it make sense to? I could do unions, but not sure if there is any real benefit to that

Answer (score 10):

In SQL Server 2008, the maximum number of tables you can have in a SELECT is limited only by available resources ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)).

In SQL Server 2005, there was a 256 table limit for a single SELECT ([source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/maximumcapacityspecificationsinsqlserver2005/1574/)).

Though, if you're getting up to those sorts of numbers, then I'd be getting a bit concerned tbh!

Comment: "Raymond Chen notes that if you have to ask where the operating system limits are, you're probably doing something wrong" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/pushing-operating-system-limits.html

Comment: The only time I've ever seen anyone hit the limits was when they foolishly used views to call views which called views, etc.  If you are using views to call views, it is time to stop now while your system is still functional (not only will you run into the limits, but you will have sever performance problems long before you run into the limits of waht can be called).

Comment: We did legitimately hit the 256 limit in SQL 2005 once.

Answer (score -5):

For `inner join`, max 256 tables can be joined.
For `outer join`, max 2 tables can be joined.

Source: classroom training.

Comment: I suggest you ask for a refund on this training. It is trivial to write a query showing that more than 2 tables can be outer joined.