# how many joins can a sql query have

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

How many INNER JOIN s can a query tolerate

```
SELECT table0.person_name, table5.animal_name 
FROM table1 
JOIN table0 ON table1.person_id = table0.person_id
JOIN table5 ON table1.animal_id = table5.animal_id
WHERE table1.aa = input1 
  AND table1.bb = input2 
  AND table1.cc = input3 
  AND table1.dd = input4
```

Comment: http://ayazahmad.wordpress.com/2007/01/26/sql-server-join-limit-exceeds-in-filtered-views-the-maximum-number-of-tables-in-a-query-260-was-exceeded/

Comment: If you ever even get close, you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: @jamiec what is wrong please explin it as an answer

Comment: Jamiec means that the limit is so large that you should never run into it.

Comment: Limits for SQL Server 2008: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2558667/877069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) link provides all of the relevant statistics.  Versions of SQL Server after 2005 don't have a hard limit on number of joins, but instead it is limited by "available resources".  For any sane query, you're not going to run out.