# What is wrong with this sample query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT table0.person_name, table5.animal_name 
FROM table1 
JOIN table0 ON table1.person_id = table0.person_id
JOIN table5 ON table1.animal_id = table5.animal_id
WHERE table1.aa = input1 
  AND table1.bb = input2 
  AND table1.cc = input3 
  AND table1.dd = input4
```

an answerer said

If you ever even get close, you're doing it wrong :) – Jamiec 1 hour ago

whats wrong with it?

Join = inner join anything else?

Comment: what are your expected results?

Comment: To say what's wrong you might want to provide a little more context as to what you are trying to achieve, what's the structure of your database, any sample data, what's the expected result, etc... Also you might ask `@Jamiec` to elaborate more on his arguments.

Comment: I assume this is related to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180276/how-many-joins-can-a-sql-query-have In which case the Jamiec quote was in answer to the question *"how many joins can a sql query have"?*

Comment: In what way is this related to VSTS or C#?

Comment: Maybe you should name your tables something other than table1, table2, etc.

Comment: I really do not see anything wrong here. If your table structure is correct and you are getting the expected results then you are good. Can you throw more light ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `If you ever even get close, you're doing it wrong :)` comment was in direct answer to the question: `What is the maximum number of inner joins can a SQL query have?`.

Indeed there is a limit to this number of joins, with all (most) DBMSes, including SQL Server, but this is not a practical limit, i.e. if you approaching it, your database / query structure probably needs to be revised.
**Edit**: It appears that with SQL2008 this limit has been removed (or rather "pushed" to "*Limited only by available resources*").  In SQL2000, the limit was 256, cf `"Tables per SELECT statement"`(which I think is one of the relevant limiting factors) in the following Microsoft documentation pages

- [MSSQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933149%28SQL.80%29.aspx)
- [MSSQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

I didn't find -nor look for in earnest- the SQL 2005 documentation.  Also note that the SQL 2000 limit of 256 can likely be artificially boosted by introducing views (would one wish to go beyond a readily monster-ish 250+ tables query ;-) )

The query shown, in this question is quite proper syntactically and semantically, and will likely be efficient and provide the desired results; this of course depends on the specific intent and the particular indexes available (if the tables are "big").

*[Stackoverflow] **Point of order**:  typically you should try and address this kind of follow-up questions within the very original posting (unless the new question effectively discusses other concepts or issues, rather independent from the original question).*